# How to print data like username after login[php- codeigniter]

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, authentication, xampp

I try to print user id and it works but when I try to print username i try different methods from net but nothing works for me. can someone help me to print username :D

looks like this:
[what it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7l9K.png)

View:

```
<h1>Hi <?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'];?></h1>
    <h1>Hi <?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?></h1>
```

Controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
            redirect("admin/dashboard");
        }
        $data=[];
        if (isset($_SESSION['error'])){
            $data['error']=$_SESSION['error'];
        }else{
            $data['error']="NO_ERROR";
        }
        $this->load->view('adminpanel/loginview',$data);
    }
    function login_post(){
        print_r($_POST);
        if (isset($_POST)){
            $email=$_POST['email'];
            $password=$_POST['password'];

            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `backenduser` WHERE `username`='$email' AND `password`='$password'");

            if ($query->num_rows()){
                $result= $query->result_array();
                //echo"<pre>";
                //print_r($result);
                **$this->session->set_userdata('user_id',$result[0]['uid']);
                $_SESSION['username']=$result->username;**
                redirect('admin/dashboard');
            }else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Invalid Credentials');
                redirect('admin/login');
            }
        }else{
            die("invalid input!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are not setting it in session properly, can you provide the output of $result that you are getting.

Comment: @BhimaniRutvik i added a pic what it appears in browser, how can I set it properly. sorry I'm really new to this

Comment: Array
(
    [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1656410476
    [user_id] => 1
    [username] => 
)

Comment: I need an output of query @javax but no worries still i posted an answer you can check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumption:- you are getting user data in $result variable as same as you get id

```
function login_post(){
print_r($_POST);
if (isset($_POST)){
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `backenduser` WHERE `username`='$email' AND `password`='$password'");

    if ($query->num_rows()){
        $result= $query->result_array();
        //echo"<pre>";
        //print_r($result);
    

        $session_data = array(
                'user_id' => $result[0]['uid'],
                'username' => $result[0]['username'],
             
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);

        redirect('admin/dashboard');
    }else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Invalid Credentials');
        redirect('admin/login');
    }
}else{
    die("invalid input!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
        redirect("admin/dashboard");
    }
    $data=[];
    if (isset($_SESSION['error'])){
        $data['error']=$_SESSION['error'];
    }else{
        $data['error']="NO_ERROR";
    }
    $this->load->view('adminpanel/loginview',$data);
}
function login_post(){
    print_r($_POST);
    if (isset($_POST)){
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `backenduser` WHERE `username`='$email' AND `password`='$password'");

        if ($query->num_rows()){
            $result= $query->result_array();
            //echo"<pre>";
            //print_r($result);
        

            $session_data = array(
                    'user_id' => $result[0]['uid'],
                    'username' => $result->username,
                 
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);

            redirect('admin/dashboard');
        }else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Invalid Credentials');
            redirect('admin/login');
        }
    }else{
        die("invalid input!");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Result still the same

Array
(
    [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1656412863
    [user_id] => 1
    [username] => 
)

Comment: Thanks for the effort bro, changing the part 'username' => $result[0]['username'] solved my problem.